# ASP.NET MVC Routing when using from cancel button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I am using a ParentChild routing pattern throughout my web application that will have Urls such as this.

Using a ParentChild MapRoute that greatly simplifies my controller methods through out the application.

```
https://localhost:44307/ProjectTestEvents/549084af-0e7a-4d2d-a709-04c599ca778e/Details/895d72c1-f667-49d8-b487-5705931b82c9
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ParentChild",
            url: "{controller}/{parentid}/{action}/{childid}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", 
                           parentid = UrlParameter.Optional,
                           childid = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        );
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult Details(GenericParentChildModel ParentChild)
{
    // do some stuff ...
}
```

Model class:

```
public class GenericParentChildModel
{
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentDescription { get; set; }
    public Guid ChildId {get; set; }
    public string ChildDescription { get; set; }
}
```

I want to apply this same approach when a user selects the cancel button of a form and the navigation is being redirected to the previous point.

On the form, I have a Cancel button that calls a generic Return method that contains a RedirectToAction.

```
public ActionResult Return(GenericParentChildModel ParentChild)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Details", new RouteValueDictionary(
               new { controller = "ProjectTestEvents", action = "Details", 
                    parentid = ParentChild.ParentId, 
                    childid = ParentChild.ChildId }));
}
```

The Url will result in a Url with querystring params ...

```
https://localhost:44307/ProjectTestEvents/Details?parentid=549084af-0e7a-4d2d-a709-04c599ca778e&childid=76bd0fd7-fd4f-4ff1-b357-8a2acc8c6ff7
```

instead of the desired ParentChild format.

```
https://localhost:44307/ProjectTestEvents/549084af-0e7a-4d2d-a709-04c599ca778e/Details/895d72c1-f667-49d8-b487-5705931b82c9
```

The query string version works but I would rather retain the url structure that was used when the user initially accesses that path.

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't change

```
url: "{controller}/{parentid}/{action}/{childid}"
```

to

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{parentid}/{childid}
```

or add route attribute

```
[Route("~/ProjectTestEvents/Details/{parentid}/{childid}
public ActionResult Details(GenericParentChildModel ParentChild)
```